# matplotlib gui respond to axes changes

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, matplotlib, axes

I have created a little GUI with QT which set's up a single matplotlib `figure` and `axes`.
The GUI has controls to change just about everything to do with the appearance of the `axes`.

Basically, it does this by each widget emitting signals back up to the main frame and it calls the appropriate matplotlib `setters` on the `axes` and `figure` objects.

However, it is possible for the `axes` (and therefore the image displayed on the `FigureCanvas`) to change without input from the GUI (e.g. when autoscaling, or adding certain plots which adjust the axes automatically). 
In this case, a widget controlling e.g. the limits of the x axis will now be displaying the wrong values.

I would like all the relevant widgets to update when the axes updates....how could I possible achieve this?

I'm thinking that this is a problem that has been solved before - how to enable a two-way communication between distinct objects?

Comment: This is actually a complicated endeavor - do you know for sure that you have to do things in a way which will auto-adjust?  i.e. perhaps instead of adding a subplot in an automatic way, you could modify/set the axes sizes yourself and update the widgets accordingly.

Comment: The problem is when you call a matplotlib routine to create a new plot (such as `axes.pie`), matplotlib will adjust the axes itself, so any widgets which were controlling the axes are now out of sync...
To always manually be in control would require rewriting a good portion of matplotlib, which I'd rather avoid..

Comment: Indeed, I guess it was just a thought if the operations were simple enough.  My only other idea is perhaps an "updater" method that goes into your plot hierarchy and accesses the various getters to obtain the right values with which to update the widgets?  That way you could call it after any plot call.

Comment: I think you are trying to re-invent model-view-controller

Comment: @tcaswell. Not trying to reinvent at all. Trying to see how matplotlib can fit into mvc (if that is what is required to do this), if at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
fig.canvas.draw() 
time.sleep(1e-2)
```

whenever anything writes to the plot? however it's hard to help with no code.
Showing an example of how your code is not working would help a lot.

**EDIT**:

I'll try this again then:
What about getting the state of the plot you are updating? I guess its what @Ajean means by updater method. I know that Artists in matplotlib have an `Artist.properties()` method that returns all of the properties and values.

I imagine Axes would have a similar method.

A quick look at the matplotlib docs yielded 2 interesting methods of axes:
`ax.get_autoscale_on()`
 and 
`ax.set_autoscale_on()`.

`ax.set_autoscale_on(False)` will prevent plots from updating the state of the axes.

Comment: You have misunderstand the question. I have no problem getting the canvas to update. I want the widgets which the user uses to control the axes to update with the relevant parameters. These widgets might be to e.g. control the axes gridline colour

Comment: Again very little information to go on here...
I assume youa re familiar with updatesEnabled... http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html

Comment: Also, only added an answer 'cause I can't comment on questions, no rep yet, your -1 didn't help :P

Comment: @nico not being able to comment on questions is *not* a good reason to post an answer.

Comment: @Ajean First of all, sorry for trying (yet it was sarcasm). Second of all: Not being able to ask for clarifications I did the best I could, i.e. answered the question as it was understood (which was obviously a blatant demonstration of poor understanding on my part, I'll give you that). I would actually disagree with you and say that there are no good reasons not to post an answer (no emphasis needed, I assume you can read). However would you get good at it if not by trying. I believe that's what the edit functionality is for.

Comment: @nico I didn't have any problem at all with the fact that you posted an answer which attempted to answer the question as it was understood at the time (btw that dv isn't mine, although the answer before the edit is really not very good), my comment was aimed at your last comment which indicated to me that you already knew your answer wouldn't be very good and only posted it because of lacking comment ability. I just don't want people to get the idea that posting a NAA in lieu of commenting is acceptable. And btw comment priv is at 50 rep so you're good now anyway.